# How to Retrieve Column Headers of a Select Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

How it is possible to retrieve column headers of a select query as a single column in SQL Server ? (it is preferred to retrieve data type of columns )

Query example:

```
select a.PartId, a.PartName, b.GroupName 
from Parts as a 
inner join Groups as b on a.GroupRef = b.GroupId
```

Expected result:

```
Columns 
--------
PartId
PartName
GroupName
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to create a temporary table with the schema of resultset and then query `tempdb`'s schema table to get the column names and details. You can get all needed details.

```
    select a.PartId , a.PartName , b.GroupName into #yourtable
    from Parts as a inner join Groups as b 
    on a.GroupRef = b.GroupId
    where 1=2

    SELECT c.name as columnname,t.name as datatype
    FROM tempdb.sys.columns c
            inner join tempdb.sys.systypes as t on t.xtype = c.system_type_id
    WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#yourtable');
```

Comment: @user3540365 : added! :)

Comment: is it possible to create a function for this purpose?

Comment: @Behnam : unfortunately, you cannot create a temporary table in function. So, No!

Comment: you can create a normal table and use @@spid column to insert and select data temporally

Answer (score 6):

Starting from `SQL Server 2012+` you can use [sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878258.aspx) to get all metadata about result set:

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5787cd733f5013fa69d1cc9e50e360b9)**

```
DECLARE @tsql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
  N'select a.PartId , a.PartName , b.GroupName 
from Parts as a inner join Groups as b 
on a.GroupRef = b.GroupId';

SELECT name AS [Columns]
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(@tsql, NULL, 1)
```

Comment: One good reason to move on from SQL Server 2008 R2 to future ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT 'PartId', 'PartName', 'GroupName'
    UNION ALL
    select a.PartId , a.PartName , b.GroupName 
    from Parts as a inner join Groups as b 
    on a.GroupRef = b.GroupId
```

Comment: It is a simple example , i need this solution for queries containing more than 20 fields.

Comment: yeah...its kinda demo but you can always drag the column name tables from the Object explorer and it will automatically put all the column names there for you.

Comment: And then you can use the above logic.